# как создать временный каталог для приложения android откуда программы очистки могут удалять файлы?

Tags: java, android

как создать временный каталог для приложения android откуда программы очистки могут удалять файлы?

Comment: getExternalFilesDir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой каталог уже есть, используйте [Context#getCacheDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getCacheDir()) или [Context#getExternalCacheDirs()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalCacheDirs())